# Appearance of horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

why does horizontal scrolling appear on a page in the mobile version?  And if you scroll down to the middle of the site, the horizontal scroll disappears.
https://nicesender.com/

Perhaps the problem is in the fixed block live-chat. But I never understood why blocks are expanding, which is the reason why horizontal scrolling appears.

Comment: That is because of aos animation you have use one possible solution for that set overflow property to body hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AOS Animate plugin is the reason the scroll bar appears. If you want to solve this issue you have to apply CSS style.

```
.main_page { overflow-x: hidden; }
```